# Using Docky as launcher

Tags: docky

I was using Gnome Do in Natty, with Docky as launcher.

Now I see that Docky and Gnome-Do have separated, and I wonder: is it possible to use Docky as launcher? Is there a way to summon docky with a key combination and then start typing the name of an application and have Docky guess it and open it for you?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend to install [Synapse](https://launchpad.net/synapse-project). It works like you know it from Docky. I switched from Docky/Gnome-Do to Synapse because of its high performance.  Just run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:synapse-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install synapse
```

More info on [OMG!Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/09/semantic-launcher-synapse-sees-release/) or [Web Upd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/synapse-launcher-028-released-with-new.html).

Answer (score 3):

I think you will be happy with this. Its called Cardapio. You can use the "super+space" and call the menu then search and run. It has a full menu plus web results, commands and software availability.

## Installation in Ubuntu

Cardapio can easily be installed in Ubuntu versions 10.04 (Lucid Lynx), 10.10 (Maverick Meerkat), 11.04 (Natty Narwhal), and  11.11 (Oneiric Ocelot). To install, simply follow the steps below:

1) Run these commands in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cardapio-team/unstable && sudo apt-get update
```

2) Now pick one or more of these, depending on how you want to use Cardapio:
$ sudo apt-get install cardapio-gnomepanel # <-- to install the Gnome-Panel applet

$ sudo apt-get install cardapio-docky             # <-- to install the Docky applet

$ sudo apt-get install cardapio-awn                # <-- to install the AWN applet

$ sudo apt-get install cardapio-gnomeshell  # <-- to install the Gnome-Shell applet

$ sudo apt-get install cardapio                         # <-- to use it in stand-alone mode only

3) Done!

To search for files in your computer using Cardapio, you need to install Tracker 0.8.7 or above. To install it on Ubuntu:
 `sudo apt-get install tracker`

[image]  Try to give you an idea of what the program looks like

[image]  This image is how it is incorporated into docky. If you click on docky the cardapio menu pops up.

Comment: I already had a launcher, Gnome Do. What I miss is using the Docky interface. I dont want to use Any other launcher. I want the looknfeel of Docky, but with the launcher options it had on Jaunty.